# Convert Uppercase to Lowercase from Input with redux in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am trying to remove all white spaces with the input. Actually, the input is clubbed with redux, whenever there is an onChangeText , its been props to action and then, getting the value from the props.

I need to remove all white spaces after typing finished , or on typing. But couldnt achieve that.

My form Code:

```
<FormInput
    underlineColorAndroid='#2980b9'
    placeholder='Having Promo Code ? Enter here !'
    onChangeText={value => this.props.onCouponCodeChanged(value)}
    value={this.props.enteredCode}
/>
```

My Redux Action :

```
export const onCouponCodeChanged = (value) => {
    return {
        type: COUPON_CHANGED,
        payload: value
    }
};
```

My Reducer:

```
 const INITIAL_STATE = { enteredCoupon: '' }

 export default (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
         case COUPON_CHANGED:
             return {
                 ...state,
                 enteredCoupon: action.payload,
                 errorForCoupon: ''
             };
             ...
 }
```

How to remove all the white spaces ? when i do that in action, its doing it lively. I just want to remove by without showing to the users

Comment: Can you explain what white space you want to remove?

Comment: While user typing " One two " need to remove white space between one and two for example @mccambridge

Answer (score 0):

Do it in your reducer when you set it in state

```
 const INITIAL_STATE = { enteredCoupon: '' }

 export default (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
    case COUPON_CHANGED:
        return {...state, enteredCoupon: action.payload.replace(/ /g,''), errorForCoupon: 
    ''};
.....
 }
```

Just make sure you bind the value of input directly from state

**Edit**

If you want to keep it in that way then perhaps you want spaces to be removed only when you actually use that coupon, for example if you want to apply the coupon say in backend build in json then just convert it using the same logic, for example

```
const transformedCoupon = coupon.replace(/ /g,'');
applyCoupon(transformedCoupon)
```

Comment: While doing this, its happening lively. ! So when we type with a space, i can see its removing the space lively ! This isnt expected